# Problem with Third Person Camera and Player Movement binding

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera

I'm working on a Three.JS game project with a third person camera. I finally got the camera to rotate properly when pressing the left and right arrow keys but its Z-axis rotation became bound to the player's forward and backward movement. This is causing the camera to pan in and flip, then pan back out while moving. I've been piecing the logic together bit by bit (reviewing documentation, tutorials, and examples), but I'm lost on where this effect is coming from.

I've tried to decouple the effect by having the scene become the lookAt object but this made the rotation worse. Other attempts included removing or changing values of the camera positions but most broke the function of the update section altogether.

Above the `animate()` section:

```
...

//Camera//
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75, 
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000)

let cameraXOffset = 0 
let cameraYOffset = 3
let cameraZOffset = -30
let cameraOffset = new THREE.Vector3(cameraXOffset, cameraYOffset, cameraZOffset)

...

//Instantiates the camera as a child of the cube object (player)
cube.add(camera)

...
```

Within the `animate()` section:

```
...

//Third Person Camera//
const tpcPosition = new THREE.Vector3().addVectors(cube.position, cameraOffset) 
camera.lookAt(cube.position)
camera.position.copy(tpcPosition)

        
//Player Movement//
cube.velocity.x = 0
cube.velocity.z = 0
        
/*These first two rotate the camera and the player. This was the desired result and does not need to be adjusted unless it solves the overall problem.*/

if (keys.arrowleft.pressed) cube.rotation.y += 0.02;
else if (keys.arrowright.pressed) cube.rotation.y += -0.02;

if (keys.a.pressed) cube.velocity.x = -0.05
else if (keys.d.pressed) cube.velocity.x = 0.05

if (keys.a.pressed && keys.shift.pressed) cube.velocity.x = -0.15
else if (keys.d.pressed && keys.shift.pressed) cube.velocity.x = 0.15
  

/*These are the forward and backward velocities that are bound to the camera's rotation.*/
if (keys.s.pressed) cube.velocity.z = 0.05
else if (keys.w.pressed) cube.velocity.z = -0.05

if (keys.s.pressed && keys.shift.pressed) cube.velocity.z = 0;
else if (keys.w.pressed && keys.shift.pressed) cube.velocity.z = -0

...
```

This should be all the relevant code for the movement and camera.